# My site doesnt output laravel page...What shoud i do?

Tags: laravel

On browser, typing `localhost/spa1/public` or `spa1.test` doesn't output the laravel. I've been stuck and cant even proceed to starting my project because of this. I really need help!!

[image]

The output supposedly :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYSS0.png)

The app key is :
APP_KEY=base64:lEpLqsi9GOqaz6eyu5VaTft0UOfj7u+A4LAie6LEJoc=

I'm using xampp on windows
My problem is y it doesnt output the Laravel page like the Google one?

Comment: Check your .env file if its there and it has APP_KEY

Comment: This is not an error, this is the default home page of **Laravel 8**

Comment: Is your problem absolut the url? Are you using xamp on windows?

Comment: You have two images shared both with the word "laravel" in them. Is that what you aim to see or is that what you are currently seeing and if so what do you aim to see?

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal, you should start the server.

```
php artisan serve
```

This will create a home URL like localhost:8000 and read index.php file in the public folder.

BTW, the image you share is Laravel's default home page. If you look at welcome.balde.php file, you can see the same content there. So your app is running. But it's not a good idea to display your app without artisan serve.

Comment: I've been following a tutorial from Traversy Media and he seems to not have this problem. I've been following his steps and i dont understand y i do not have the same output as his. The input should be like The word Laravel at the centre of the page like Google...

Comment: Hey Norr Fie, the output you are getting is correct since you have installed the latest laravel version in your project. Go ahead with changing the view and then you will realize.

Comment: Follow up to date tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, and this is how the home page looks like in Laravel 8. Because the home page you're talking about was in Laravel 7 & below. And from Laravel 8 onwards, the default home page of Laravel 8 is updated and looks like the one you're getting right now.

[image: Laravel 8 Home page]